# CSS3 support on older browsers

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS3 concepts and am trying to understand the same.

I assume that the main benefits of using CSS3 is that it eliminates using images for doing stuff like gradients, rounded borders, etc

My question is if I want to support older browsers, say IE8, what are my options;

> 1. Will it automatically fallback to some rendering on older borwsers (e.g. normal borders instead of rounded)
> 2. Can I get the same effect on older IE browsers (e.g. rounded borders) using some other libraries ? (i.e. rounded borders or gradients on IE)
> 3. In CSS3 examples, I see a lot of things or properties like -webkit, -moz, -o , etc What are these used for ? Is there any specific order that is required for these to have older IE fallback support ?

Comment: For your third point : those are specific elements for web rendering engines (webkit is a library for rendering engines). For example, each rendering engine has diferent ways to make animations. So they are specific to each engine. And since everything is moving really fast, you should focus on the new technologies instead of the older ones (I don't force you to do so, this is just an advice).

Comment: Did you tried Google? Pasting your exact title will give this article: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/03/using-css3-older-browsers-and-common-considerations/ as thefirst result. Where it has the answer for everything in this post.

Comment: 2) depending on the feature you want to render, there are various "workarounds" from polyfill (implementing somehow the same visual effect) to "gracefull degradation" (it doesn't look that nice on older browser, but it's still functional), passing by simple CSS fallback with or without CSS hacks or IE conditonnal comments. So basically it depends on what you want to achieve and which browsers you need to support. The older the browser, the heavier the solution to get the exact same result...

Comment: @Bartdude One of those cases is the creation of gradients for IE6-8.

Answer (score 3):

1. In most cases yes. Sometimes browsers have partial implementations which may differ from majority of others. You can check CSS3 support on this awesome resource - [**Can I use? - border radius**](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)
   It shows you information per browser / per version, has annotation about partial supports and shows global support percentage.
2. For implementing fallbacks on older browsers you would want to use feature detection library like [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/). It adds bunch of css classes to html element based on users client and its CSS3 support. e.g.

   `<html class="js no-touch postmessage history multiplebgs boxshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients csstransforms ....`

   When it comes to implementation of fallbacks there are different techniques for each different case. Below are examples of fallbacks for background gradient using Modernizr:

   ```
   /* 1px wide bg.png image with gradient stretched to div width */
   .no-cssgradients div.header {
       background: url(images/bg.png) repeat-x;
   }

   /* 
      IE-specific implementation 
      Uses filters supported only by IE browsers
   */

   .no-cssgradients div.header {
       filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 );
   }
   ```

   Next technique you can employ is detection of IE version by using conditional comments. You will have to add following code snipped on top of your index.html

   ```
   <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
   ```

   Now each specific version has it's own set of `lt-*` classes. Afterwards I create `iefixes.css` file where I put all nasty ie fixes. It is very convenient as all hacks are in one place and as soon as you drop support for some verison you can easily delete part of them or even remove whole file.  e.g.

   ```
   /* Applied for all IE version < 9 (IE6-8) */
   .lt-ie9 .header {
       margin-left: 20px;
   }
   ```

   [**How to create IE-only stylesheet**](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)
3. These are CSS vendor prefixes. CSS browser prefixes are a way for browser vendors to add support for new CSS features. Browser prefixes are used to add new features that may not be part of a formal specification and to implement features in a specification that hasn’t been finalized. No difference in the order applied.  [Source](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm)

   There are number of tools which automatically add vendor prefixes, you may want to preprocess your css source during a build, then you don't have to maintain them yourself.

   [**Prefixfree**](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) **/** [**Autoprefixer**](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer)

Answer (score 0):

1) Yeah, though your mileage may vary. Sometimes it'll fall back as you suggest, sometimes it'll go crazy (if you're doing something particularly complicated). Some things (e.g. animation) have no equivilent fallback.

2) Your best option is http://css3pie.com/ - a quick plugin that adds (most) css3 options to older IE browsers. IE8 usage is fairly low in most countries (approximately 15% globally), though as Raptor points out still high in places like China if the international market is a concern. Ironically, you're probably more stuck on IE6 as there are still some companies using that because of legacy code.

3) The prefixes are/were necessary to make CSS3 work on some browsers. A list of what's currently required can be found at [W3 Scools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp) and [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/)?, but a lot of them have been dropped now and you can go with the vanilla versions.

Comment: Nice answer, but IE8 usage is quite high in China, and ~15% globally (*Source: NetMarketShare, May 2015*). See also http://ie8countdown.com

Comment: @Raptor, fair point. My own audience is primarily UK based so I hadn't considered that.

Comment: Right at the end, where you say "buut a lot of them have been dropped now and you can go with the vanilla versions"

Comment: I like this answer, although it fell down on the last point with your link. Since [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/) wouldn't be the most reliable, I would rather use [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) to check browser prefixes

Comment: @jbutler483 I wasn't aware of that resource, I'll add it to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin: caniuse is kept up-to-date. w3schools would be considered a 'bad resource' and should be avoided for this kind of stuff at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, but not all CSS3 properties are recognized, e.g. keyframe animation
2. Depends on which effects. There are some libraries doing this.
3. those are vendor-specific properties. In older browsers / those browsers that does not support the CSS standards, they adopt these vendor-specific properties in order to show the CSS properties. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) has a very detailed CSS section to tell which CSS requires vendor-specific properties and which doesn't.

Comment: So for the 3rd part of the answer, it means that properties like -webkit-box-shadow, -moz-box-shadow are not CSS standards....but these would slowly get standardized and we should have only 1 definition for all browsers (sometime in future) ?

Comment: The reason for browsers using prefix is that it sees this property "experimental". It's up to the browser vendor to judge when to follow CSS standard and drops the prefix. For my own practice, I will keep prefixed version and the standard version in the same selector for maximum compatibility.

Comment: Take [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) as example. Most browsers have already dropped the vendor specific prefix since early versions, such as Chrome 10 and Firefox 4.

Comment: WHere can I check the details on the MDN link?

Comment: Just quoted the box-shadow link to you. In fact, you can Google `box-shadow mdn`, and MDN will show up in the first few results.

Comment: caniuse.com is also a nice resource to understand CSS browser compatibility.